# How to Escape Comma within Formula in CSV file

Tags: excel, csv, escaping

I'm trying to create a CSV file (Excel or LibreOffice) which contains a formula that uses multiple arguments separated by a comma. The comma is interpreted as a field separator. Is it possible to escape the comma somehow so formula requiring commas can be used?

This works as expected:

```
=Sum(A1:A10)
```

This doesn't read correctly due to use of comma in formula:

```
=Confidence.Norm(.01, Stdev.p(A1:A10), 10)
```

Imagined solutions that don't work:

```
=Confidence.Norm(.01 \, Stdev.p(A1:A10) \, 10)
=Confidence.Norm(.01 ',' Stdev.p(A1:A10) ',' 10)
=+"Confidence.Norm(.01 \, Stdev.p(A1:A10) \, 10)"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
"=Confidence.Norm(.01, Stdev.p(A1:A10), 10)"
```

Comment: Thanks. That works in Excel. Works in LibreOffice if I use their formula names "=Confidence(.01, Stdev(A1:A10), 10)" I really thought your answer was going to be treated as text but, no, it really does get treated as a formula.

Comment: No problem - faced this issue a lot working with bibliographic data - i.e Author names, surname first etc etc :)  Glad I could help.  Happy New Year!

Comment: My formula contains both commas and quotation marks (")
Do you know how I can put both?

Comment: Double your quotes to escape them.